# Let $X$ be a simply ordered set having the least upper bound property. In the order topology, each closed interval in $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

I do not understand why $C$, defined as the set of all points $y > a$ of $[a, b]$ such that the interval $[a, y]$ can be covered by at most two elements of $A$ (a supposed covering) does not work.

What is the problem of this assumption in the proof?

(I am in the proof of the theorem 27.1 of Munkres topology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know why Munkres couldn’t have defined $C$ to be the set of all points $y>a$ of $[a,b]$ such that the interval $[a,y]$ can be covered by *at most two* (instead of *finitely many*) elements of $\mathscr{A}$.

Recall how the argument proceeds after he defines $C$: he lets $c$ be the least upper bound of $C$, shows that $c\in C$, and then shows that $c=b$. This shows that $b\in C$, meaning that $[a,b]$ can be covered by finitely many elements of $\mathscr{A}$. If this argument could be carried out with your version of $C$, it would prove that every open cover of a closed interval in $X$ had a subcover consisting of at most two sets. This, however, is false. $\Bbb R$ is a linearly ordered set with the least upper bound property, $[0,1]$ is a closed interval in $\Bbb R$, and the open cover

$$\mathscr{A}=\left\{\left[0,\frac13\right),\left(\frac14,\frac34\right),\left(\frac23,1\right]\right\}$$

does not have any proper subcover: you need the first set to cover $\frac18$, the second to cover $\frac12$, and the third to cover $\frac78$, for instance.

We can also locate the precise point at which the argument would fail. It’s in Munkres’ *Step 3*, where he writes this:

> Since $z$ is in $C$, the interval $[a,z]$ can be covered by finitely many, say $n$, elements of $\mathscr{A}$. Now $[z,c]$ lies in the single element $A$ of $\mathscr{A}$, hence $[a,c]=[a,z]\cup[z,c]$ can be covered by $n+1$ elements of $\mathscr{A}$.

Notice that although we needed only $n$ elements of $\mathscr{A}$ to cover $[a,c]$, we needed $n+1$ to cover $[a,c]$. Granted, this was in aid of producing a contradiction, but the problem that it illustrates is real. In my example above, for instance, we can cover the interval $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ with just the first two members of $\mathscr{A}$, but in order to cover $[0,c]$ for any $c\in\left[\frac34,1\right]$ we need to include the third member.